# Displaying a sum from data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have two tables, an INVOICE SUMMARY table and an OUTSTANDING ORDERS table. They both contain the BUYER ID (customer unique reference).

Before linking in the second outstanding orders table, I have successfully created a report to show performance metrics for each individual customer. For example, total sales, total costs, and total profit and profit percentage (calc fields).  All the data is accurate and is grouped by customer.

Now we want to see information on outstanding orders for each customer - internally, we call this Orders In Hand (OIH).

I thought it would be very straight forward, since both tables have the same unique field of BUYER ID. But when ever I insert a ANY field from the second outstanding orders table, the information on invoices (customer performance) goes all wrong!

It seems that for every time a BUYER ID appears within a row in the outstanding orders table, I get duplicated records within the invoice summary page. All my totals are multiplied and therefore are correct.

What I want to see is the summary data for a customer within the invoice table and then just bring in there sum of outstanding orders from the second table.

I have tried adjusting the table relationship over and over again but this does not effect the result. As soon as I remove all fields which I want to display from the second table, the report becomes correct again.

I am hoping the attached image helps explain this. The field in green square is showing correctly 8 units are outstanding, but then the main report has duplicated invoices, and ignored the summary process.

[image]

I was expecting since I added the field QUANTITY OUTSTANDING on the Group 1 line, Crystal would summarise the results where it matches the BUYER ID in the second table and have no effect elsewhere!

Here is the SQL table code from Crystal - probably not enough data!

```
SELECT "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Invoice_Date", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Goods_Value", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Charges", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Total_Costs", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."CostedCharges", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Tax_Base_Total", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Charges_Costs", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Buyer_ID", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Company_Name", "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Invoice_Reference", "ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding"."Quantity", "ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding"."Quantity_Shipped"
 FROM   "CS_Interex_Test_KSL"."dbo"."vw_Invoice_Summary_01" "vw_Invoice_Summary_01" LEFT OUTER JOIN "CS_Interex_Test_KSL"."dbo"."ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding" "ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding" ON "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Buyer_ID"="ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding"."Buyer_ID"
 WHERE  ("vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Invoice_Date">={ts '2024-01-01 00:00:00'} AND "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Invoice_Date"<{ts '2024-02-01 00:00:00'})
 ORDER BY "vw_Invoice_Summary_01"."Buyer_ID"
```

Here is the code for a simple formula field that I bring in from the second table, that makes it all go wrong.

```
{ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding.Quantity} - {ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding.Quantity_Shipped}
```

Comment: I think we need to know more about the data structure. Does each table list each order, as in, do they both have a record for 951028, then another for 951029?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, as markdown tables, not images

Comment: Hi @Dan The INVOICE SUMMARY table is a collection of ALL completed invoices we, and will only contain a record for 951028 or 951029 once. Totals of the invoice are detailed only - no invoice line items. Regarding the second table, OUTSTANDING ORDERS doesnt include any reference to 951028 or 951029. It is a table containing details of ALL sales orders which have not yet completed and therefore do not have an invoice number. BUT both tables have a link, which is a Customer ID.

Comment: Hi @DaleK thank you for your help, I have included some more information above in the form of SQL code.

Comment: Hi Craig, so it seems the ksl_vw_rep_CustomerOrdersOutstanding has multiple entries for each Buyer_ID (one entry for each outstanding order), as does vw_Invoice_Summary_01 (one entry for each invoice) so when you join on Buyer_ID you get every invoice row repeated by every outstanding order.  There are several ways to fix this, probably the easiest is to group first on Buyer_ID, then Group again on Invoice_Reference. ... to be continued

Comment: continued... This will give you all one group header/footer per each invoice, within the grouping for the Buyer_ID. The Details section will still by repeated for each outstanding order. In the Buyer_ID header instead of normal summations, use running total fields and sum evaluating on change of the invoice group. In the Invoice group header place the sum of the outstandin orders, then supress the details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *record inflation* due to the way you are joining the data.

Here are some options to get around the problem:

1. Create and join to a database view that summarizes the data from Outstanding Orders by customer. That is the best option.
2. Use a correlated SQL Expression to bring in the summary data for each customer.
3. Use a subreport.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I don't have access to edit/design the main database, so I am unable to create a View which summarises the data. Are you suggesting that my link to the second table is wrong? and what would you think it should be. It is currently a Left Join, but I have tried all others available.